# CRM 2011: How to let a processing workflow run very long

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a crm 2011 workflow with a assembly which will run about 1-3h depending on the amount of data. How can I make this happen in the sandbox?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The sandbox service has a processing limit of 2 minutes, so this certainly won't be possible for CRM Online. You may be able to update the sandbox processing limit if you are on-premise, but I don't recommend it for a 1-3 hour process, because you'll quickly run out of worker processes and other workflows and plugins will fail.

You should probably set up an external web service that does this work. Then in your workflow assembly, fire off the external web service. That way you can explicitly control timeouts in a separate web application.

Comment: Josh is right. Even if the architecture allowed you to, you wouldn't want to clog up your server with a process that will run for so long. You should probably consider Azure Extensions for CRM which utilizes the Service Bus to offload data to Azure for processing. Check here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309276.aspx